# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner

Tags: java

In project commons-dbutils-1.5-src I have got class QueryRunner in package org.apache.commons.dbutils. I am making such kind of analisys of code from dbutils by another java project. There I am using Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner"). 
This ends with:

```
 ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.
```

It happens also to other classes from dbutils project...

In program arguments I indicate:

```
 -w ...\workspace\commons-dbutils-1.5-src
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `classpath` correctly for the jar containing the `QueryRunner class` file. or otherwise add it to the `library for your project`.